# Redmine not finding my Git Repo on Debian 7.3

Tags: debian, git, redmine

I'm currently facing the problem, that I get the error message `The entry or revision was not found in the repository.` when I want to see the repository in Redmine 1.4.4. The repository path is set to `/var/redmine/git_repositories/db-hdr.git/` in Redmine. In the Apache error.log would always appear:

```
fatal: Not a git repository: '/var/redmine/git_repositories/db-hdr.git/'
fatal: Not a git repository: '/var/redmine/git_repositories/db-hdr.git/'
```

But it IS a git repository, like you can see in this screenshot:

http://s7.directupload.net/images/140104/eh3asd5m.png

I really don't know what else I could do to find a solution, therefore I am asking for your help to get Redmine to work with git repositories...

You will probably need more information, but I don't know what further information could help you, so if you need more logs or anything, please ask me to provide them.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Chris

Comment: This might be a problem with your file permissions. If you do `sudo -u www-data bash; cd /var/redmine/git_repositories/db-hdr.git/; git status`, do you get the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using .git directory in repository settings.
I mean change this path:

```
'/var/redmine/git_repositories/db-hdr.git/'
```

to this:

```
'/var/redmine/git_repositories/db-hdr/.git'
```

or something like this.

It helped me with redmine 2.5-stable branch. I found this solution here: http://simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/07/configuring-git-repository-with-redmine/